# Dynamically referring to JSON node in Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a function that extracts a node from JSON document as follows:

```
...
Json  = GetJson(Url),
Value = Json[#"values"]
```

values correspond to the actual node within the JSON document.

I would like to generalize this piece of code and provide the name of the node as a variable like:

```
let myFunc = (parentNodeName as text) =>
...
Json  = GetJson(Url),
Value = Json[parentNodeName]
```

However getting this error:
`An error occurred in the ‘myFunc’ query. Expression.Error: The field 'parentNodeName' of the record wasn't found.`

How can I refer to the JSON node dynamically?

Comment: [`Record.Field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerquery-m/record-field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
(Json, parentNodeName ) =>
let
...
Value = Record.Field(Json,parentNodeName)
in Value
```

sample code:

```
let Json = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://soundcloud.com/oembed?url=http%3A//soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood&format=json")),
Value=myFunc(Json,"title")
in Value
```

and myFunc:

```
(Json, parentNodeName ) =>
let 
Value = Record.Field(Json,parentNodeName)
in Value
```